# Get file ID and path to use in a template file

Tags: 7, views, theming, media, files

I am working in my **Row style template** (`views-view-fields--MYVIEW--block-1.tpl.php`). I need to get the file ID and path of an image. The image field is a multi field, so I need to get all of the images for each row. How do I do this?

I also will need to get the delta value of each image.

I try using kpr($variables) but I can't click to expand:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$var)` function in the `template.php` in your theme directory is get called just before loading the Row Views Template file. Every component of the current row is saved inside the `$var` array.

To get what you need, simply just `kpr($var)` and it gives you all of the information about the current row. You can also save these information in the `$var` array as an index and use them later.

Comment: I tried kpr($variables) in my view template. It shows Array 30 elements but I can't expand it to see. Do I need to change a setting? Krumo display is set to default

Comment: Only one click on any of them expand it. Was there any js error in console?

Comment: No js error. Updated question with screenshot of kpr output

Comment: How many recordes the View displays? And how many fields each row has? Since this function is get called for every row so if the View contains many rows it maynot work properly. Limit the View to show just 1 record

Comment: I have multiple multi fields that I will need to loop through somehow. The multi fields are Image, Link (to a pdf file), and Caption. Each of these need to display for each row.

Comment: try using `dsm()` instead of `kpr()`